# Crystal Reports: Adding Max Value per Group in a Group header section

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, sum, report, max

I am getting the max amount per group, and I want to get the sum of all the max values but crystal report won't Summarize it. Crystal Report states the Field cannot be summarize?

How can it be done?

Comment: Your question is a little confusing. The title says "Adding Max Value per Group in a Group header section", which you state you have already done. So where exactly do you want the sum of the max to be displayed?

Answer (score 0):

it's possible, but it's a bit tricky, or at least my solution to the problem is.
You have to create 2 formula fieds the first is MaxValue and its formula should be something like this:

```
Shared NumberVar SharedMax;
SharedMax := SharedMax + maximum(AmountField, GroupingField);
```

Put this field in the group footer and suppress it

then you create a second formula field called TotalMax and the code is

```
Shared numberVar SharedMax;
SharedMax;
```

Put this in the report footer and you'll have the total of all max value of each group